# Datatype missmatch in c#

Tags: c#, database

Why my code show this message

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

The attribute `Fine` is in number datatype.

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string cq = "select sum(Fine) from Studentbook where Student_ID='" + textsearch.Text + "'";
command.CommandText = cq;
int a = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
connection.Close();
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString(), "Your FINE is", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/  If I were a QA tester, I would enter `';DROP TABLE Studentbook;` in `textsearch.Text`.

Comment: @EricJ.: You missed a quote.

Comment: @SLaks: Think I edited it in already, but let me know if it's still wrong :-)

Comment: i had a problem in Datatype. unfortunately i use number datatype in table and text data type in code.but now i corrected it and solved the problem

Comment: You should use command parameters to avoid making mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

Other than possible `SQL Injection` vulnerability; the said error could be because of the `WHERE` part in your query; where `Student_ID` is number and you are trying to compare it with string type data.

```
where Student_ID='" + textsearch.Text + "'"
```

Considering that your `Student_ID` is of `INT` or `NUMBER` type column change your code to be like below. Notice the use of parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection

```
string sql = "select sum(Fine) from Studentbook where Student_ID = @studentid";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", Convert.ToInt32(textsearch.Text.Trim()));
```